# Mower runs for a bit then smokes, sputters and dies

Tags: briggs-stratton, lawnmower

I have a Murray rear-engine riding lawn mower with a Briggs & Stratton 875 Series (190 cc) electric start engine. When cold, the mower starts up first try and runs well. After a few minutes, it begins to sputter and dies shortly afterwards. It begins smoking pretty bad as it is sputtering/dying. It does start back up after a few tries, but it immediately begins smoking and sputtering and then dies. I have tried running it without the air filter with no change.

Comment: Does the smoke smell like oil?  In other words, has it been overfilled with oil?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Sure could use more info. How recent has this started? Was is all of a sudden or been getting worse over time? How old is the gasoline in the tank? Has the carb been cleaned recently? Have you tried a little Sea Foam in the gas?

Answer (score 1):

Several things could be the cause with your limited explanation of the symptoms.  To further refine things, you should do the following:

-check the spark plug and describe what it looks like

-check the oil and describe it's looks and level

-do you smell gas after the shutdown

-how long until it starts again, and what is the engine temp when it starts?